Should I Re-optimize Without CHGCAR When Switching from vasp_gam to vasp_std?
I have been performing structure optimization in two steps to reduce computational cost: first, I use vasp_gam to quickly reach a local minimum, and then I switch to vasp_std for the final structure optimization. During this process, I’ve been using the CHGCAR file generated from the vasp_gam calculation as the initial charge density for the vasp_std run, with ICHARG=1.
However, since the k-point mesh changes between vasp_gam and vasp_std, I am now questioning if it’s appropriate to reuse the CHGCAR file in this way. Would it be more accurate to start the vasp_std calculation with only the CONTCAR as the new POSCAR and without a CHGCAR file, thus recalculating the charge density from scratch?
Thank you for any insights on whether my approach is valid or if starting from scratch in the vasp_std step is recommended.

I have never restarted VASP calculations when changing the binary. However, I know that changes to the k-point mesh are not an issue when restarting using CHGCAR file, as said in the CHGCAR documentation:

Tip: We recommend starting from the CHGCAR file when repeatedly restarting with small changes in the input parameters, e.g., the k-point mesh (KPOINTS).

Using the CHGCAR is standard procedure when evolving parameters such as ENCUT or k-grid, and when converging magnetic or LDA+U calculations. The only thing you need to pay attention to is whether NGX, NGY and NGZ have changed, as noted in the VASP forum.

Thank you very much for your valuable answer!
